# Local hosting with Azure

Tags: azure

Is possible to utilise your own servers along with Azure for a web app? 
I mean can I set up so the hosting of my web app that is currently running in Azure only that it also runs on some local servers through their load-balancer so I essentially get more instances of the server without paying for them by using my own servers as well?

Comment: The short answer: Yes. The longer answer: This is a bit broad / off-topic for Stack Overflow, since there are so many ways to accomplish this. You might want to start by looking at Azure Traffic Manager, which is designed specifically for balancing traffic across multiple regions (whether cloud or on-premises). I'm sure there are other ways to accomplish this; just wanted to point out the specific 1st-party service designed for this (since you asked specifically about Azure).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible but you might find yourself not saving much money if you do it correctly to make sure the solution is secure.  You would need to consider an architecture that might include creating a Site-to-Site VPN between you Azure vnet and you on-premise network which would also include an VNET Gateway.  If your company is already doing this (VPN) or using something like ExpressRoute then you are already absorbing those costs.  When looking at costs...there are many things that you need to consider when comparing using the cloud (whether it is AWS or Azure) versus on-prem.  For web apps that are not overly complex...it is almost impossible to beat the cost of running them in the cloud these days when you factor in hardware capex, man-hours maintaining the hardware and OS running on it, security related expenses, etc.